# pagination of xlsx file to XSSFworkbook using apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Right now in my code, I am reading a xlsx file, into an XSSFWorkbook, and then finally writing it into a database. But, when the size of xlsx file increases, it causes an outOfMemory error.
I can not increase the server size, or divide the xlsx file into pieces.
I tried loading workbook using file (instead of inputstream), but that didn't help either.

I am looking for a way to read 10k rows at a time (instead of the entire file at once) and iteratively write to the workbook and then to the database.

Is there a good way to do this with Apache POI?

Answer (score 1):

POI contains something called an "eventmodel" which is designed exactly for this purpose. It's mentioned [in the FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10066):

> The SS eventmodel package is an API for reading Excel files without loading the whole spreadsheet into memory. It does require more knowledge on the part of the user, but reduces memory consumption by more than tenfold. It is based on the AWT event model in combination with SAX. If you need read-only access, this is the best way to do it.

However, you may want to double check first if the issue is somewhere else. Check out [this item](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10109):

> 14. I think POI is using too much memory! What can I do?
>       This one comes up quite a lot, but often the reason isn't what you might initially think. So, the first thing to check is - what's the source of the problem? Your file? Your code? Your environment? Or Apache POI?
>
> (If you're here, you probably think it's Apache POI. However, it often isn't! A moderate laptop, with a decent but not excessive heap size, from a standing start, can normally read or write a file with 100 columns and 100,000 rows in under a couple of seconds, including the time to start the JVM).
>   Apache POI ships with a few programs and a few example programs, which can be used to do some basic performance checks. For testing file generation, the class to use is in the examples package, SSPerformanceTest. Run SSPerformanceTest with arguments of the writing type (HSSF, XSSF or SXSSF), the number rows, the number of columns, and if the file should be saved. If you can't run that with 50,000 rows and 50 columns in HSSF and SXSSF in under 3 seconds, and XSSF in under 10 seconds (and ideally all 3 in less than that!), then the problem is with your environment.
>   Next, use the example program ToCSV to try reading the a file in with HSSF or XSSF. Related is XLSX2CSV, which uses SAX parsing for .xlsx. Run this against both your problem file, and a simple one generated by SSPerformanceTest of the same size. If this is slow, then there could be an Apache POI problem with how the file is being processed (POI makes some assumptions that might not always be right on all files). If these tests are fast, then any performance problems are in your code!

Comment: Hi Ray, I tried to explore more details as per your guidelines, but still I couldn't find the way to do it. Please suggest some piece of code